# Add the new "email" scope to Google Apps Marketplace SDK

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I can't add the new "email" scope to Google Apps Marketplace SDK in the Google APIs Console. This scope is supposed to replace the depreciated https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email scope (as commented in https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#email). What should I do to ensure future compatibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

email & profile are functionally equivalent to userinfo.email & userinfo.profile, respectively. They even share a mapping on the backend. You can safely use email & profile in your code today and won't have to worry about migrating in the future.

Comment: Strangely, when I use the "email" scope, each individual user has to approve the authorization request during the installation, while with the "userinfo.email" scope the global domain-wide admin approval is enough (as it should be). So there must be some kind of difference.

Comment: Hmm...odd. Are you using the standard Web Application flow or a Service Account?